# Having Trouble With JComboBox and TreeMap

Tags: java, jcombobox, treemap

My Probem is I want to display the keys of my map as a JComboBox and it is only displaying one of them, this code is just the part I am having problems with, if readers don't see the problem in the code I have I will list the other classes on here as well. So basically I have my keys as an Instuctor object and values as a set of Student objects (One instructor has more than one student), when I create the JComboBox it is only displaying one of the keys. I tried a different ordering because I thought maybe it was only using the last key added (like the keys were getting replaced) but that wasn't the issue that I could see. Anyway this is getting lengthy so here is my code.

```
    //Test Objects
    TreeSet<Student> inst1Student = new TreeSet<Student>();
    TreeSet<Student> inst2Student = new TreeSet<Student>();
    TreeSet<Student> inst3Student = new TreeSet<Student>();
    inst1Student.add(new Student("Jane Doe"));
    inst2Student.add(new Student("Jhon Smith"));
    inst3Student.add(new Student("Students Name"));
    Instructor inst1 = new Instructor("Instructors Name1", inst1Student);
    Instructor inst2 = new Instructor("Instructors Name3", inst2Student);
    Instructor inst3 = new Instructor("Instructors Name3", inst3Student);
    theList.put(inst1, inst1.getStudents());
    theList.put(inst3, inst3.getStudents());
    theList.put(inst2, inst2.getStudents());
    //Make combo box
    instructors = new JComboBox<>();
    getInstructorsArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < theInstructors.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(theInstructors.get(i));
        instructors.addItem(theInstructors.get(i));
    }
    panel3.add(instructors);
    instructors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("You Clicked Someone");
        } 
    });
```

and to reference this is the getInstructorsArrayList() method that I have.

```
public static void getInstructorsArrayList() {
    for (Entry<Instructor, Set<Student>> entry : theList.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() != null) {
            theInstructors.add(entry.getKey().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Instructor Class:

```
package psl_Tracker;

import java.util.Set;

public class Instructor implements Comparable<Instructor> {

    private static String name = null;
    private static Set<Student> students = null;

    public Instructor(String name, Set<Student> students) {
        Instructor.name = name;
        if (students != null) {
                   Instructor.students = students;
        }
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Instructor other) {
        return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
}
```

And again any help would be appreciated, I feel its a little mistake that I am just not seeing. Also any syntax errors anyone sees please tell me (Its a pet peeve of mine).

Comment: Show your `Instructor` class code, I think your exception in that class. I need to see `compareTo()` implemantion and `hashCode()` method if that overrided.

Comment: Where is `theInstructors`

Comment: theInstructors is an ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the ArrayList to an array and add it by default to the combobox constructor

```
public JComboBox generateCombo (Arraylist<String> toConvert){
    String[] arrayListToArray = toConvert.toArray(new String[toConvert.size()]);
    JComboBox testbox = new JComboBox(arraylistToArray);
}
```

Comment: I get the error "cannot convert from object[] to string[], and I have tried your method (A little bit different instead I returned a String[]) and initialized the JComboBox where I needed to initialize it originally. Also tried casting it and I get a RunTime error ClassCastException.

Comment: sorry... toConvert.toArray(new String[toConvert.size()]); modified my solution

Comment: This got rid of the null pointer exception, thank you. My only other problem now that I can't figure out is my JComboBox is only displaying one item, not all three (Instructors Name3). Any thoughts on this problem or shall I ask another question.

Comment: Have you tried to simply print the ArrayList to look what is in there?

Comment: Yeah I did and only Instructors Name3 was in it, I ended up remaking my code with Netbeans and it worked out for me.